# DBT Installation on Command Prompt Not Working

Tags: command-line, command-prompt, dbt

[Here is the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRCil.png)

I tried the  pip install dbt-core according to the website and it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: Please don't add images of code or console errors. See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: What version of python are you running and what is your dbt-core version?